# Rotating all rows of the data frame using loop

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, for-loop, rotation

`df` has 40 distinctive subjects, each has 10 different images. Each row will be one image data.

Row 1-10 will be the 10 images for the first subject.
Row 11-20 will be the 10 images for the second subject. etc.

`df` has 40 columns and 400 rows.

I figured out how to rotate the first image of the first subject. However, I want to apply it to all subjects by rotating each and every row in the dataset. The first image of the first subject is `df[11,]` the last image of the last subject will be `df[3910,]`.
ex, 9th photo of the 36th subject : `df[359,]`.10th photo of the 8th subject : `df[710,]`.

I'm stuck with applying it to the all images in all subjects using for loop. Hope to figure it out using loop. (`rnow` and `byrow` should be fixed as it is.)

```
library(magick)
library("OpenImageR")

# the first image of the first subject
a <- matrix(as.numeric(df[1,]), nrow=64, byrow=T)

## rotate the matrix, and name it as "a_rotated"
a_rotated <-  rotateFixed(a, 90)
```

Below is where I'm stuck, but it must be a wrong direction. Could anyone help me rotating each and every row in the dataset?

```
for (i in 1:399){
   a[i]<-matrix(as.numeric(df[i, ]), nrow=64, byrow=T)
   a_rotated <-  rotateFixed(a[i], 90)
}
a_rotated
```

Comment: Perhaps `sapply(df,function(x)sapply(x,rotateFixed,angle = 90))` will work for you?

Comment: No it doesn't. Could you be more specific on x and how to apply it within the context?

Comment: `function(x)` in this case is a lambda function, a function defined temporarily to do other things. `sapply` works column-wise on a data.frame. The column is then worked on element-wise in the second `sapply` call. But your data must not be stored in the data.frame the way `rotateFixed` expects. As a final attempt you might try `sapply(df,function(x)sapply(x,function(y)rotateFixed(as.matrix(as.numeric(y)),angle = 90))` Otherwise, I fear you will have to provide some reproducible data if you'd like a perfect answer.